# How to pass ID in kendo command

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

```
 columns: [
        {
            field: "Name",
            title: "Name"
        },
        {
            template: "<div>#if(data.Count > 0){#<a class='undo' onClick='showSiteName(#:Id#,`#:Name#`)'>#:Count# </a>#} else{#N/A#}#</div>",
            field: "Count",
            title: ""
        },
        {
            command: [
                { name: "edit", template: "<a class=\"k-icon k-i-edit\"  onclick='onButtonClick(#:Id#)' title=\"Update\"></a>" },
                { name: "delete", template: "<span class=\"k-icon k-i-delete\" title=\"Delete\"></span>", visible: function (data) { return data.Count == "0" } }
            ],
            title: "Action"
        }
    ]
```

In abouve code onButtonClick(#:Id#) ,actually i want to pass ID as a parameter but now i am getting ID not defined error message .

How can i pass on clicked line ID to this function in kendo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove the `onclick` event you've setup. Then setup the `dataBound` event for your grid. Inside the event, bind to the edit button's `click` event. Inside the `click` event, do the following:

1. Get the closest `tr`
2. Get the data item by calling the `dataItem` method from the kendoGrid, passing the `tr`
3. Get your data point from the data item

Here is an example:

```js
dataBound: function() {
  $('.k-grid-edit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var tr = $(e.target).closest("tr");
    var data = $("#grid").data('kendoGrid').dataItem(tr);
    var id = data.Id; 
    console.log(id);
  });
}
```

Fiddle: https://dojo.telerik.com/ADiteHOc

Comment: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dataItem') . i am getting like this

Comment: @xyz - you will need to change `#grid` with the selector you're using for the kendoGrid. You didn't include that in your code so I just guessed the selector.